# toggling display states oddity

Tags: jquery, css

I have this jQuery toggle that swaps the display of one div with another. Now, if I click on link1 (displays the div.shows), then move off it, and the back on, I cannot click it (or my home button) again unless I click link2 (div.depts). Am I messing up something in my CSS or did I set my true/false states incorrectly in my jQuery?

Here is the jQuery:

```
var displayShow = false;
var displayDept = false;
var containerHeight = 130;
$(".showLinks").click(function() {
    if (displayDept) {
        toggleDisplay(".depts",0,0);
        displayDept = false;
        console.log("displayDept: " + displayDept);
    }
    if (displayShow) {
        toggleDisplay(".shows",0,0);
        displayShow = false;
        console.log("displayShow: " + displayShow);
    } else {
        toggleDisplay(".shows",1,containerHeight);
        displayShow = true;
        console.log("displayShow: " + displayShow);
    }
});
$(".deptLinks").click(function() {
    if (displayShow) {
        toggleDisplay(".shows",0,0);
        displayShow = false;
        console.log("displayShow: " + displayShow);
    }
    if (displayDept) {
        toggleDisplay(".depts",0,0);
        displayDept = false;
        console.log("displayDept: " + displayDept);
    } else {
        toggleDisplay(".depts",1,containerHeight);
        displayDept = true;
        console.log("displayDept: " + displayDept);
    }
});
function toggleDisplay(divClass,divOpacity,divHeight) {
    $(divClass).animate({
        opacity: divOpacity,
        height: divHeight
    });
}
```

And the rest can be found here:
http://jsfiddle.net/jawa9000/xn8WB/1/

Comment: Lemme debug :-) Upvoting question.

Answer (score 0):

**Looks like this may be the culprit:**

```
<div class="homeLink">
<a href="#">Home</a>
</div>
    <div class="showLinks">Links1</div>
    <div class="deptLinks">Links2</div>
```

**You are targeting:**

`$(".showLinks")` &&
`$(".deptLinks")`

In your **Javascript** I don't happen to see any `div` for your **home** link, or any *reference* to them... `homeLink` is isolated.

Answer (score 0):

I think my problem is with the  elements. When a div slides down to be hidden, the  element is still being displayed as table-cell instead of display: none.

To fix this, I just added the following link to the my if/else statements:

```
$("div.link1/link2 ul").css("display","none/table-cell");
```

Thanks for playing!